# one-to-many filtering in media database

Tags: java, sql

With [pms-mlx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pms-mlx/), I've been working on a media library to extend the functionalities of the [ps3 media server](http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/) for some time now and just recently discovered a major flow in my concept; it is not possible to filter if using more than one one-to-many property.

Before asking questions, I should explain how it works.
Here's the DB structure for the relevant part of the code. [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) is being used.
[image: DB schema video]
Every video is a file and has 0-n of the attached properties.

Once some videos have been stored, it is possible to view and play them in folders showing only a subset of all entries, by setting conditions. Here's an example:
[image: pms-mlx condition example]

To retrieve the wanted files, the query is being constructed like this

```
SELECT <all_properties> 
FROM FILE, VIDEO
LEFT JOIN VIDEOAUDIO ON VIDEO.FILEID = VIDEOAUDIO.FILEID
LEFT JOIN SUBTITLES ON VIDEO.FILEID = SUBTITLES.FILEID
LEFT JOIN FILETAGS ON VIDEO.FILEID = FILETAGS.FILEID
LEFT JOIN FILEPLAYS ON VIDEO.FILEID = FILEPLAYS.FILEID
WHERE <whereClause>
ORDER BY <orderBy>
```

Only the where and order by parts are dynamic. The where clause is being created by replacing the condition names (c1, c2) by their corresponding SQL counterparts. For the above example this where clause will be generated:

```
WHERE VIDEO.FILEID = FILE.ID 
  AND ((VIDEO.NAME LIKE 'A%' OR VIDEO.NAME LIKE 'B%') 
  AND FILE.DATEINSERTEDDB > '2011-09-28 18:48:43')
```

When doing the query, many rows will be returned for each file. While iterating through the results, the 'new' data contained in the raw will be added to create the object.

When the filter contains a one-to-many condition, the query is being done in two steps. First, the IDs of all the videos are being retrieved and then the data loaded.

What I've been missing until now, is that if having e.g. two file tags and both should be met, nothing works anymore.
If setting the filter:
[image: not working filter example]
Resulting in this where clause:

```
WHERE VIDEO.FILEID = FILE.ID 
  AND ((VIDEO.FILEID = FILETAGS.FILEID 
    AND FILETAGS.KEY = 'Actor' AND FILETAGS.VALUE LIKE 'A%') 
  AND (VIDEO.FILEID = FILETAGS.FILEID 
    AND FILETAGS.KEY = 'Actor' AND FILETAGS.VALUE LIKE 'B%'))
```

which is never met, as a single row only contains one key and one value field.

Would it be possible to create a query where all the data for a single video would be contained on one row? Or substitute the generated SQL condition by something else?
I'm no db expert and would love to here from someone having a good idea :)

The code to generate the where clause is in the method formatFilter on line 445 of [DBFileInfo.java](http://pms-mlx.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pms-mlx/trunk/ps3mediaserver_mlx/net/pms/medialibrary/storage/DBFileInfo.java?revision=55&view=markup). The loading of the data is being done on line 189 of [DBVideoFileInfo.java](http://pms-mlx.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pms-mlx/trunk/ps3mediaserver_mlx/net/pms/medialibrary/storage/DBVideoFileInfo.java?revision=55&view=markup) if anybody is interested to see the code.

Comment: I currently can imagine these solutions. 1) Find a sub-query with a nested select which could be used as 'c1'. 2) Port all this to hibernate (AFAICT the query could then be done with criterias) 3) Do a post processing after having loaded the data (I'd like to avoid this one, as the equation would have to be separated into two blocks for the SQL query and the post processing; looks pretty tricky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your complex table relationships is a bit confusing for a simple example of the problem, but can you not just build a bunch of criteria up?

```
WHERE FILEID IN (SELECT [all files that have brad])
AND FILEID IN (SELECT [all files that have angelina])
AND FILEID IN (SELECT [all files that have elvis])
```

Surely that would only return files that have Brad, Angelina *and* Elvis in? (Probably not many).

Comment: This could very well be the answer but I wasn't too sure how to start off with nested selects. I'll try it when I can, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm. A bit slower than the other queries, but it integrates fully into the existing code

Comment: Yes, the performance of many nested SELECTs can be a nightmare, especially if there is poor indexing on them.  I work with one product that has an audit table that has *no* indexes, and the data as XML in a single varchar, and not even a PK.  Those queries take a while...

Answer (score 1):

You need your GUI to let user specify if he/she wants filter to work as `AND` or `OR`. In your last case, obviously, you need `OR`. So your `WHERE` clause will look like:

```
WHERE VIDEO.FILEID = FILE.ID 
  AND VIDEO.FILEID = FILETAGS.FILEID
  AND FILETAGS.KEY = 'Actor'
  AND (FILETAGS.VALUE LIKE 'A%' OR FILETAGS.VALUE LIKE 'B%')
```

Notice that repeatition of common conditions is eliminated and common piece is moved out to upper level of `WHERE`.

I think you'll need both your GUI and SQL generator for this.

---

**UPDATE** In case you need both 'A%' and 'B%' to be in result movies, you need change `WHERE` clause to

```
WHERE VIDEO.FILEID = FILE.ID
  AND EXISTS
  -- look if movie have 'A%' actor
  (SELECT 1 FROM FILETAGS WHERE 
  AND VIDEO.FILEID = FILETAGS.FILEID
  AND FILETAGS.KEY = 'Actor'
  AND FILETAGS.VALUE LIKE 'A%')
  AND EXISTS
  -- look if the same movie have 'B%' actor
  (SELECT 1 FROM FILETAGS WHERE 
  AND VIDEO.FILEID = FILETAGS.FILEID
  AND FILETAGS.KEY = 'Actor'
  AND FILETAGS.VALUE LIKE 'B%')
```

Anyway, these are just *samples* how queries may look like, depending on user's input. 
Original question, how I understood it, was about particular situation, not a general solution. Clearly, in general case, your application will need to employ different conditions reflecting user choice in GUI.

For general case, you'll need some form of "SQL Builder", like [this one](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/sqlbuilder/). Or you may want to employ some ORM tool which will build SQL semi-automatically for you. But if you don't know SQL very well, I'll advise you to start with SQL builder to get some low-level SQL experience. Using ORM properly entails good understanding of SQL and related stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't cover all the cases I'd like to. Let's take a people example; where we want to have all movies where Brad Pitt and Angelina Jolie are actors.

Comment: It's still doesn't work. It won't select anything in example you've given. There's no row in FILETAGS having value BOTH like 'A%' AND 'B%', hence no row will be returned.

Comment: With the current implementation, the second query will always have 0 rows in the result set, as for a single result row only one key-value pair will be available (where the value will never start with A and B). That's why I was asking if it is possible to get all video properties on a single row. Otherwise the algo has to filter upon multiple rows from the result set. I'm wondering how a OR-mapper would perform the job; would this all be done in SQL or would there be post-processing? SQL Builder could do the job; currently I've got my own builder creating the query.

Comment: To clarify, I'd like to cover all cases where a filter is being created through the GUI. Currently, filters containing only one-to-one conditions work optimally; filter containing one one-to-many conditions work (by doing two DB queries); filter containing more than 1 one-to-many condition of the same type don't work.